# error with opening an Excel file ( .xlsx ) with matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to opening and 'xlsx' file with matlab command and I get this

> error:" ??? Error: Call Was Rejected by Callee"

Here is the command that at use:

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application'); % Ouverture de l'application Excel
Excel.Visible = false;  % le fichier excel sera invisible
xlspath = pwd
xlsfile ='test.xlsx'

Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(fullfile(xlspath,xlsfile));% Ouverture du fichier  Excel
' Error: Call Was Rejected by Callee.
```

I don't know what can be the problem. I'm using excel 2013 and matlab 2009.

<sub>The French error is *L’appel a été rejeté par l’appelé.* which is similar as mentioned in [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/329854) but that didn't solved my issue</sub>

Comment: English error message would be more helpful.. Is the excel file exist or closed when you try to run the code?

Comment: @Arpi Rene's working on it.

Comment: here is the error message in eenglish @Arpi : "The appeal was rejected by callee"

Comment: can you give me the link please? @rene

Comment: thanks but I don't think this article addresses my problem @rene

Comment: someone else has a suggestion please?

Comment: Are you sure `fullfile` gives you the correct path to your xslx file? Can you output the content of `Excel.DefaultFilePath` befire you open the workbook?

Comment: i have check your command and the same error appear. I have seen this code in a forum and it works on excel 2007. maybe i think that it is excel 2013 the problem @rene

Answer (score 0):

If you were to change

`Excel.Visible = false;`

to

`Excel.Visible = true;`

your file should open.  My experience has been that MATLAB errors with `Error: Call was rejected by callee.` when the `.xlsx` Excel file is invisible.